# SQL Syntax != error

Tags: sql, syntax-error

I know I should be able to see it, but I am getting syntax error on last line. Any ideas?

```
select Problem_Investigation_ID, 
       dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, getutcdate(), getDate()) , dateadd(second, submit_date, '1970')) as submit_date, 
       dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, getutcdate(), getDate()) , dateadd(second, last_modified_date, '1970')) as last_modified_date,
Target_Resolution_Date, char_Status, description, assigned_group, Priority
from PBM_Problem_Investigation
where Assigned_Group  in ('xxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxx'   )
and char_status  != ('Completed', 'Closed', 'Resolved')
```

Comment: Doh, just realized it should be Not In

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
char_status   not in  ('Completed', 'Closed', 'Resolved')
```

Answer (score 1):

!= or <> is used only when there is only one value. As you are dealing with multiple values, try

```
not in  ('Completed', 'Closed', 'Resolved')
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your query..

```
SELECT Problem_Investigation_ID, 
   dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, getutcdate(), getDate()) , dateadd(second, submit_date, '1970')) as submit_date, 
   dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, getutcdate(), getDate()) , dateadd(second, last_modified_date, '1970')) as last_modified_date,
   Target_Resolution_Date, char_Status, description, assigned_group, Priority
FROM PBM_Problem_Investigation
WHERE Assigned_Group  in ('xxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxx'   )
        and char_status  NOT IN ('Completed', 'Closed', 'Resolved')
```